When i try to log out / shut down I get an error message : type of message (yb) does not match expected type (b)
I have the above problem. Other users have asked the same question but the fixes suggested don't work for me. Any other ideas? Thanks

This question is similar to: How fix GDBus.Error: org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.InvalidArgs: Type of message, "(yb)" does not match expected type "(b)"?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Thanks for your advice.

Answer one was
Clear the session cache.
open Settings -> Settings Manager -> Session and Startup -> Saved Sessions -> Clear saved sessions
However, when I go to 'session and startup' there are no saved sessions so...?

There is 2 answers there

Answer 2 is: I could solve this by deleting the folder /home/USERNAME/cache/sessions. But I can't find this folder anywhere on my computer.
